# Java8 Stream How to iterate through elements from back to front？

Tags: java-8, java-stream

For example:

```
List<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList(3, 1, 2)
for(int i = list.size() - 1; i>=0; i--) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

How do I go about implementing the above code in Java8 Stream?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below piece of code -

```
ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.listIterator(list.size());
Stream.generate(iterator::previous)
  .limit(list.size())
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

What if something like:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(3, 1, 2);
    Collections.reverse(list);
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This is incorrect, he has to flip the elements of the set first and it will become slower

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array = {3, 1, 2};
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, array.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> array[array.length - i])
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't think of such a simple method

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.